# How to normalize values in a dataframe column in different ranges

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dataframe, normalization

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    T  data
0   0    10
1   1    20
2   2    30
3   3    40
4   4    50
5   0     5
6   1    13
7   2    21
8   0     3
9   1     7
10  2    11
11  3    15
12  4    19
```

The values in `T` are sequences which all range from 0 up to a certain value whereby the maximal number can differ between the sequences.
Normally, the values in `data` are NOT equally spaced, that is now just for demonstration purposes.

What I want to achieve is to add a third column called  `dataDiv` where each value in `data` of a certain sequence is divided by the value at `T = 0` that belongs to the respective sequence. In my case, I have 3 sequences and for the first sequence I want to divide each value by 10, in the second sequence each value should be divided by 5 and in the third by 3.
So the expected outcome would look like this:

```
    T  data   dataDiv
0   0    10  1.000000
1   1    20  2.000000
2   2    30  3.000000
3   3    40  4.000000
4   4    50  5.000000
5   0     5  1.000000
6   1    13  2.600000
7   2    21  4.200000
8   0     3  1.000000
9   1     7  2.333333
10  2    11  3.666667
11  3    15  5.000000
12  4    19  6.333333
```

The way I currently implement it is as follows: 
I first determine the indices at which `T = 0`. Then I loop through these indices and divide the data in `data` by the value at `T=0` of the respective sequence which gives me the desired output (which is shown above). The code looks as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'T': range(5) + range(3) + range(5),
                   'data': range(10, 60, 10) + range(5, 25, 8) + range(3, 21, 4)})

# get indices where T = 0
idZE = df[df['T'] == 0].index.tolist()

# last index of dataframe
idZE.append(max(df.index)+1)

# add the column with normalzed values
df['dataDiv'] = df['data']

# loop through indices where T = 0 and normalize values
for ix, indi in enumerate(idZE[:-1]):

    df['dataDiv'].iloc[indi:idZE[ix + 1]] = df['data'].iloc[indi:idZE[ix + 1]] / df['data'].iloc[indi]
```

My question is: Is there any smarter solution than this which avoids the loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following approach avoids loops if favour of vectorized computations and should perform faster. The basic idea is to label runs of integers in column 'T', find the first value in each of these groups and then divide the values in 'data' by the appropriate first value.

```
df['grp'] = (df['T'] == 0).cumsum()           # label consecutive runs of integers
x = df.groupby('grp')['data'].first()         # first value in each group
df['dataDiv'] = df['data'] / df['grp'].map(x) # divide
```

This gives the DataFrame with the desired column:

```
    T  data  grp   dataDiv
0   0    10    1  1.000000
1   1    20    1  2.000000
2   2    30    1  3.000000
3   3    40    1  4.000000
4   4    50    1  5.000000
5   0     5    2  1.000000
6   1    13    2  2.600000
7   2    21    2  4.200000
8   0     3    3  1.000000
9   1     7    3  2.333333
10  2    11    3  3.666667
11  3    15    3  5.000000
12  4    19    3  6.333333
```

(You can then drop the 'grp' column if you wish: `df.drop('grp', axis=1)`.)

As @DSM points out below, the three lines of code could be collapsed to into one with the use of `groupby.transform`:

```
df['dataDiv'] = df['data'] / df.groupby((df['T'] == 0).cumsum())['data'].transform('first')
```

Comment: That looks great and works fine, thanks! I upvote it for now and might accept it later on depending on the quality of other answers.

Comment: Not worth a separate answer, but alternatively you could use `.transform("first")` and then divide by `x` instead of `df["grp"].map(x)`.  Amounts to the same thing.

Comment: @DSM: Thanks for this comment. I am still exploring the power of pandas so I am always glad to learn something new.

Comment: @DSM: thank you for the suggestion - `transform` simplifies the code somewhat. I've edited it into my answer.